# How to expand on result of first query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

This is my first time using Postgres and I would like to write a query that expands on the elements in an array. The example is as follows.

I have some object in a table, say

```
+-----+------+----+
| 123 | john | AZ |
+-----+------+----+
| 456 | carl | CA |
+-----+------+----+
```

Another table has an object that contains an array of user ids.

```
+-----+-----------+
| 999 | {123,456} |
+-----+-----------+
```

Given the two case classes

```
case class User(userId: Int, name: String, country: String)
case class Group(groupId: Int, users: List[User])
```

I would love to write a function with this signature:

```
def getGroupById(groupId: Int): Future[Group] // or Future[Option[Group]]
```

so that

```
getGroupById(999) ---> Group(999, List(User(123, john, AZ), User(456, carl, CA))
```

For the time being I am doing it the 'brute force' way:

```
obtain group object with user ids
  ---> Future.sequence(query each user id) 
  ---> map to desired final object
```

But, could I achieve this without application logic, in one single query?
I am using the [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) extensions for Slick to manipulate arrays in Postgres.